# Angular default select option being overwritten

Tags: angularjs

My drop down box defaults to "No Preference" which is what I want, but it keeps getting overwritten by the other options when they load in the page. How do I keep "No Preference" as the default.

contact-form.html:

```
<p>
  <label>Preference</label> 
  <select id="name" class="form-control" ng-init="" ng-model="contact.teammate" ng-options='contact.id as (contact.firstName + " " + contact.lastName) for contact in contacts'>
        <option value="">No Preference</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("contactsApp", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/new/contact", {
                controller: "NewContactController",
                templateUrl: "contact-form.html",
                  resolve: {
                    contacts: function(Contacts) {
                        return Contacts.getContacts();                   
                    }
                  }

            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            })
    })
    .service("Contacts", function($http) {
        this.getContacts = function() {
            return $http.get("/contacts").
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("Error finding contacts.");
                });
        }
    })
    .controller("NewContactController", function($scope, $location, Contacts) {  
        console.log("Entered new contacts controller");
    Contacts.getContacts().then(function(doc) {
            $scope.contacts = doc.data;
        }, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
$scope.contact.teammate = '';
```

just under:

```
$scope.contacts = doc.data;
```

This will default it to the option with no value '' or if you want to default to something else just set the value to it.

You also need to define:

```
$scope.contact = {};
```

Do it just under:

```
console.log("Entered new contacts controller");
```

Here's a Plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/4hCSXURbc754IAHU3VyN?p=preview

I used timeout to simulate ajax delay.

Comment: I added  $scope.contact = ''; $scope.contact.teammate = ''; but the "No Preference" still gets changed to one of the names when they load.

Comment: That is because  $scope.contact is not defined, thus contact.teammate is trying to set a value to property teammate of undefined, and it won't work. I updated my answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help and Welcome to Javascript :)